# Generating an email list from AppMaker Database

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to figure out how I can get database information involving the email column, make an array with all of the emails and then use the "button" feature to populate the "To:" part of an email page.

Any help is appreciated. Very new at this and pointing me on where to get the info would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to run a server script that would query the datasource that has the emails. The script will look something like this:

```
function getEmails(){

  var query = app.models.<yourmodel>.newQuery();
  var results = query.run();

  var allEmails = [];

  if(results.length > 0){  
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){    
      var uniqueEmail = results[i].<emailfieldname>;
      allEmails.push(uniqueEmail);      
    }
  }

  return allEmails.join();      

}
```

Then add a script to the button widget "onclick" event that will run the server script and manipulate the returned data. Something similar to this:

```
function poulateToField(response){

  <widget path>.text/value = response;

}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(poulateToField).getEmails();
```

The above **widget path** would be the path to the "To:" widget, which can be a text box, text area, etc. In my case, I used a text area and the path was this "***widget.parent.descendants.TextArea1.value***"

I hope this helps. If you have more questions, just let me know! :)

P.D. Please don't forget to review the **[official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/overview)** for a better and more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use projections to get a list of items (emails) from your datasource. As per this Article https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#projections:

> Projections let you access properties from records in a datasource's
>   items list. Access projections with the ..projections.. option in the
>   advanced binding wizard, or use the projection operator .. in a
>   binding path. For example, for an Employees datasource with a name
>   property, @datasources.Employee.items..name returns a list of all
>   employees' names.

You can check the "Call Scripts" guide which shows you how to send emails using App Maker which is available here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/tutorials/call-scripts/

To use projections and following the above guide, in **Step #2** under "Create the UI": Add a text box for the recipient:

c. In the Property Editor, instead of entering the "To" value to the Textbox widget, you can select Binding and bind the widget to the Datasource projections following this path: **datasource > items > ..projections.. > Email** (name of the datasource field where the emails are located)

For example a projection will look like this: **@datasource.items..email**

This will automatically bind all emails that are available in your datasource to the text box widget. Then you can complete the guide and emails will be sent to all the email addresses in your datasource. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the easiest method as long as you have all the records on the client. If you only have some of the records on the client, e.g. a single page or a query with filters, then using a server-side script as described in other answers is best.