# What callback function do I use in the client script

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to query items on a model in my app, and I am currently able to do that in the Server Script. However, I don't know how to return the items that I queried back to the Client Script side.

This is the function that I am using on the Server script:

```
function spouseRecord(){
  var query = app.models.Dependent.newQuery();
  query.filters.Relationship._equals = "Spouse";
  var spouse = query.run();

  var payload = {
    SpouseName: spouse[0].LastName + " " + spouse[0].FirstName + " " + spouse[0].MidName,
    SpouseSSN: spouse[0].SSN,
    SpouseDateofBirth: spouse[0].BirthDate.toLocaleDateString(),
    SpouseSex: spouse[0].Sex,
  };
  return payload;
}
```

I think that this function is OK as is. My problem is on the client side. I want to obtain the object *payload*. I am using this function.

```
  var payload = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().spouseRecord();
```

I don't know what I need to place between the parenthesis of withSuccessHandler. Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a client script function that will handle the server script results. Your code should look something like this:

```
function showPayload(payload){
    console.log(payload);
}

var payload = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showPayload).spouseRecord();
```

This question seems to be a duplicate of this one [Generating an email list from AppMaker Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645111/generating-an-email-list-from-appmaker-database)