# AppMaker Return value from server side to client side

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I have on a AppMaker page a button who execute a function on the client side

```
function showall(){
  app.pages.ProjectComposant.children.Html1.html = google.script.run.showhtml();
}
```

and the function on the server side is

```
function showhtml(){
  return "<p>test</p>";
}
```

but the server not return the string. I have try to use the `withSuccessHandler()` but there is no onSucess handler on the client side script

There is another way to get a returned value from the server ? 
tanks

Comment: I strongly believe that if you study the question and answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645111/generating-an-email-list-from-appmaker-database/41646149#41646149, you'll figure it out.

Comment: thank you it works perfectly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in server side

```
function showhtml(){
  return JSON.Stringify("<p>test</p>");
}
```

in client side

```
    function showall(){

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
function(returned_result){ 
app.pages.ProjectComposant.children.Html1.html = JSON.Parse(returned_result); 
})
    .showhtml();
    }
```