# How can i use a function from Apps Script bound to my docs, with my Google App Maker application?

Tags: javascript, google-docs, google-app-maker

I'm using the following function, to create a new doc. (this function's bound with a googledoc using appscript)(it work when i execute the script)

```
function createDoc() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Document Design Compatibility');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var rowsData = [['Ex', 'xE'], ['Ex', 'xE'], ['Ex', 'xE'], ['Ex', 'xE']];
  body.insertParagraph(0, doc.getName())
      .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  table = body.appendTable(rowsData);
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
}
```

And actually , I would like to execute this function when i click on a button in my GoogleAppMaker application.

When I call `createDoc()` on the `onClick()` method of my button , it's doesn't work.

Comment: This is a very common question. You need to call the server script from the client script. It is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/client#call_a_server_script)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating an email list from AppMaker Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645111/generating-an-email-list-from-appmaker-database)

Comment: thank you very much, my question was very common i'm sorry about that. But i succeed :D